# Let Raspberry Pi connect to internet through Ubuntu in virtual machine

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet, raspberrypi

I have Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS installed in a virtual machine in OS X. There's a Raspberry Pi connected to the same mac via direct ethernet wire. The mac is connected to the internet via wifi connection.

I want to connect the RPI to the internet, but `ping <ip>`, `wget <url>` don't work. Strangely, `apt-get` IS working. In the Ubuntu virtual machine, everything can connect to the internet, no problem at all.

If i do a `sudo tcpdump -a -v -i eth1` in the Ubuntu machine and `ping 8.8.8.8` in the RPI, I can see that the traffic is reaching Ubuntu, but the RPI gets no response. I see this in Ubuntu:

```
10.0.0.101 > google-public-dns-a.google.com: ICMP echo request, id 2156, seq 1, length 64
09:49:47.008804 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22891, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
10.0.0.101 > google-public-dns-a.google.com: ICMP echo request, id 2156, seq 2, length 64
09:49:48.008648 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22985, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
...
```

If I do an `wget http://google.com`, `curl`, etc. in the RPI I always see traffic reaching the Ubuntu virtual machine, but never get anything back to the RPI.

How can I connect the RPI to the internet?

Thanks

Comment: **"In the Ubuntu VM,  everything can connect to the internet, no problem at all"**, which makes this question **an Apple question which is off topic here**.  However, on [apple.se], a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all kinds of fruity problems, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Comment: I am not sure that this is an Apple question. I can see that the traffic from the RPI reaches the Ubuntu VM, but nothing comes back. Isn't it possible that Ubuntu is not "routing it to the outside world"?
In fact, the Ubuntu VM connecting to the internet tells me that OS X is not putting any problems here...

Comment: True: It might be a pure VM question, but that's still off-topic here on Ask Ubuntu.  http://serverfault.com might be a better match in this case.

Comment: Or it could be an Ubuntu question! `apt-get` gets through, but `wget`, `ping` not. Are you 100% positive that it is NOT an Ubuntu question?

Comment: No, I'm not and that's why it takes 4 more people to vote "off topic" to actually put your question *on hold* for 5 days.  Then you still have those 5 days to [edit] and improve your question (leaving comments doesn't count) before it's finally made off-topic so *stop worrying about one vote*.  **;-)**

Comment: How does the RPI know that it should use the Ubuntu VM as a gateway?

Comment: Nevermind, I found a solution (posted below). I never was worried _about one vote_, but about people helping me to find a solution. Quite on topic at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it working. I was confused because `apt-get` was working, so I thought that everything was correctly set up in the Ubuntu VM, but it wasn't. I got the solution from this post https://support.hidemyass.com/hc/en-us/articles/202721486-Using-Linux-Virtual-Machine-instead-of-a-router-for-VPN

In your Ubuntu VM, assuming that `eth0`: internet, `eth1`: your RPI connected via ethernet cable

```
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i eth1 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables.sav
```

uncomment this line in /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

The reason why `apt-get` was working in the first place is still a mistery to me.